# Как в PDO получить строку запроса prepare после обработки

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть строка запроса к базе данных:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?
```

Я использую PDO функцию prepare:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?');
```

Нужно получить строку запроса после обработки функцией prepare, например:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 294
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Из коробки нельзя, надо извращаться. На английском СО есть здоровенный тред с кучей вариантов разной степени монструозности.

Comment: @Ипатьев, а ссылочку можете указать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements

Comment: Следует понимать, что функция prepare() **никак** не обрабатывает переданный в неё запрос, он остаётся в точности таким же.

Поэтому получать что-либо после prepare() нет ни малейшего смысла.

Если в целях отладки требуется получить исполненный запрос с подстановленными в него значениями, то можно попробовать заменить плейсхолдеры вручную.

Если же запрос с подстановленными значениями требуется для любых других целей, то делать это ни в коем случае нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [библиотеку](https://github.com/panique/pdo-debug), которая позволяет это делать

```
$parameters = array(
    'param1' => 'hello',
    'param2' => 123,
    'param3' => null
);

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:param1, :param2, :param3)";
echo PdoDebugger::show($sql, $parameters);

//shows: INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('hello', 123, NULL)
```